# EF Core Model containing itself, doesn't delete children

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

So, I'm building a function that works with models, which contains optional models of itself, which in all is working, except for on delete, where it leaves all children behind.

After fighting this for a couple of hours without progress I just have to concede that I'm obviously *not getting it*.

I've built a small demo just to boil down to what I'm trying to get to work.
And yes, the point is to be able to optionally chain the model with itself.

I'd appreciate any feedback I can get ;)

What does happen:

- Migration works fine, update-database fine
- When I insert the sample item, it looks fine

```
index                data                 child1Id             child2Id
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1                    master1              NULL                 NULL
2                    master2              NULL                 NULL
3                    master master        1                    2
```

What does not happen:

- When I remove the object as below in the codesample, it orphans the children

```
index                data                 child1Id             child2Id
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1                    master1              NULL                 NULL
2                    master2              NULL                 NULL
```

Model

```
public class Master
{
   [Key]
   public int index { get; set; }
   public string data { get; set; }
   public int? child1Id { get; set; }
   public Master master1 { get; set; }
   public int? child2Id { get; set; }
   public Master master2 { get; set; }
}
```

Test code

```
// Build the sample model            
var master = new Master()
{
   data = "master master",
   master1 = new Master() { data = "master1" },
   master2 = new Master() { data = "master2" }
};

// Add and save
_unitOfWork.Master.Add(master);
_unitOfWork.Save();

// Get it back, works fine
master = _unitOfWork.Master.GetFirstOrDefault(x=>x.data == "master master", "master1,master2");

// And remove it
_unitOfWork.Master.Remove(master);
_unitOfWork.Save();
```

DbContext OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Master>()
    .HasOne(e => e.master1)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.child1Id)
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
modelBuilder.Entity<Master>()
    .HasOne(e => e.master2)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.child2Id)
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it backwards; what you refer to as "orphaned children" are the principal entities (i.e., parents) of the relationship defined on foreign keys `child1Id` and `child2Id`.

In your example, if you were to delete one of the "master 1" or "master 2" records, the "master master" record would also be deleted as that is the dependent record.

To clear up the confusion with your example, rename the `child1Id` and `child2Id` properties to `parent1Id` and `parent2Id`.  While that may not be your design intent, it would help to clarify the relationship at which point you can decide how to proceed.

Comment: First Doh! You are so right in that I was thinking wrong about it.
This actually helps as the question is not about children but parents.
Thanks!